# WPF - How do I get the MainWindow instance?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double _frameCounter = 0;\;
```

Very new to WPF and C#, but the below (MainWindow.xaml) appears to me to be where this class is being instantiated:

```
<Window x:Class="CompositionTargetSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Composition Target Rendering Sample"
        Width="768"
        Height="512">
```

Back in MainWindow.xaml.cs, outside of the MainWindow class, I want to reference the _frameCounter field of the object instantiated in MainWindow.xaml, but don't know how to address that MainWindow object.

Comment: May i know your need of having main-window object?

Answer (score 46):

You can access your field with

```
Application.Current.MainWindow._frameCounter
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this: `Application.Current.MainWindow._frameCounter`

[Application.MainWindow MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
Window.GetWindow(App.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow
```